# Multiplication/Division: How did the author simplify $(1/64)z^-3/1-4z$ to the result in the image?

Tags: education, algebra-precalculus

[image: How did he get the result?]

I have tried multiplying the numerator and denominator by 4/z and also dividing both by 4z but alas I can't seem to get the answer.
Thank you very much to anyone who answers.

Comment: incorrectly${}$?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's indeed a little bit wrong. Let's see...
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{  \frac{1}{64}z^{-3}     }{     1 - 4z  } =&
\frac{  \frac{z}{4\cdot 16}z^{-4}     }{    \frac{z/4}{z/4} - 16\cdot \frac{z}{4}  } \\
=&\frac{ \left( \frac{z}{4} \right)  \frac{1}{16}z^{-4}     }{   \left( \frac{z}{4} \right) \left[  \frac{1}{z/4} - 16 \right]  } \\
=&\frac{   \frac{1}{16}z^{-4}     }{   \left[  \frac{1}{z/4} - 16 \right]  } \\
=&\frac{   \frac{1}{16}z^{-4}     }{ 16  \left[  \frac{1}{4}z^{-1} - 1 \right]  } \\
\end{split}
$$
when $z \neq 0$.

Comment: $(z/4)[1/(z/4)-1]=1-z/4\ne 1-4z$

Comment: @Andrei Thank you, fixed.

Comment: Ah I had a feeling it was wrong, but didn't trust my math skills enough to conclude that. Thanks!